# Как можно работать с писать и читать в сокет одновременно?

Tags: python, linux, сокет

Пишу туннель на питоне и тут стала проблема
Читать и писать с TUN/Сокета и в TUN/Сокет надо одновременно без какого либо порядка, как реализовать, Многопоточность не знаю

Comment: Изучайте многопоточность. Или мультиплексирование.

Comment: Если **одновременно** то тут без многопоточности никак не обойтись.  Можно попробовать реализовать это на *select*, отправив один конец *pipe* в  *readfds* а другой - в  *writefds* , но тогда Вам понадобятся очереди ввода/вывода, которые придётся заполнять/опустошать в многопоточном режиме. Альтернативы нет!

Comment: @Sergey Зачем многопоточность ? select обычно используется в режиме асинхронной работы в одном потоке. Наверняка ТС не имел ввиду под одновременно, что один и тот же квант времени. в 99.999% случаев асинхронности достаточно

Comment: https://pymotw.com/3/asyncio/io_coroutine.html

Comment: @Mike *один и тот же квант времени* - дело не в физической одновременности, а в том, что если *select* постоянно висит на на *fdset*-ах, то кто буде заполнять очередь отправки и обрабатывать очередь приёма?!  Пример: вот *select* соскочил с ожидания по доступности операции записи в сокет. По идее, нужно взять сообщение из очереди и записать в сокет. Хорошо... Но кто ложит сообщения в эту очередь? Должны быть ещё два потока: один что-то берёт из внешенго мира и формирует сообщения для отправки, а другой принимает сообщения и что-то делает во внешнем мире. Параллельные!!!

Comment: @Sergey Второй поток нужен только когда не хватает процессорной мощности. Если потоку приходится спать на select, вместо того, что бы выполнять работу, тут есть 2 варианта: 1. работы нет, 2. программа неправильно спроектирована. Любой внешний мир для процессора - это ввод-вывод, любой ввод-вывод (включая работу с файлами) можно завернуть в select, Откуда бы процесс не брал данные для постановки в очередь он так же делает это, когда эти данные поступили с медленного устройства и select его разбудит для этого. Кроме того у select есть таймаут

Comment: @Mike *Второй поток нужен только когда не хватает процессорной мощности.*  - дальнейшая дискуссия особого смысла не имеет... Поймите очень простую вещь: если у нас есть чёткое разделение на клиента и сервера, то можно обойтись ОДНОпоточным сервером и ОДНОпоточным клиентом. Можно даже *select* не использовать, обойтись *poll*. Но если у вас сообщения идут СЛУЧАЙНО и НЕПРЕДСКАЗУЕМО в ОБЕ стороны, нет чистого сервера и чистого клиента, то обязательно нужны два (!!!) потока - одни на вход, другой - выход. Посмотрите на архитектуру SNMP клиент/менеджер.

Comment: @Mike ещё один широкоизвестный пример - программа putty. Посмотрите, на скольки потоках она сделана.

Comment: @Sergey putty виндовая утилита. А под windows все очень грустно ибо нет единого подхода к произвольным потенциально блокирующим вызовам (вернее к их неблокирующему исполнению). Посмотрите лучше nginx https://www.aosabook.org/en/nginx.html у него при благоприятных условиях (подходящей ОС) один единственный поток на целый worker, который держит несколько сотен входящих и исходящих (в случае режима прокси) соединений, а так же обслуживает работу с внешними cgi-обработчиками

Comment: @Mike *putty виндовая утилита* - охренеть... 8-0

Comment: @Sergey Да, вижу, ошибался. Меня смутило то, что собранные версии есть только для windows. Изучил исходный код. Там собственно две вообще отдельные ветви. windows и unix. Причем в ветви windows thread активно используются, а вот в ветви unix нет ни единого упоминания. Так как я работаю в основном с unix системами, для меня работа чего либо асинхронного в единственном потоке кажется обычной практикой. Программист, более тесно работающий с windows будет считать и совершенно оправданно, что несколько потоков необходимы

Comment: @Mike *Причем в ветви windows thread активно используются, а вот в ветви unix нет ни единого упоминания.* - совершенно верно. Просто потому, что в винде нет *fork()* , а люних-программёры предпочитают использовать именно  *fork()* как более простую и надёжную штуку. Треды были придуманы специально для виндовоза, когда выяснилось, что распараллеливание необходимо, а понятия "процесс" в винде нет. 

Что бы не быть голословным: только в файле *uxpgnt.c* вызов *pid = fork();* встречается два раза.

Comment: @Sergey Да, отличный пример. Первый fork() используется для отвязывания от управляющего терминала (демонизации), т.е. основной процесс тут же завершается (`if (pid != 0) { ...  exit }`. Второй fork интереснее, порожденный процесс выполняет exec для загрузки вместо себя другой исполнимой программы, имя и параметры для которой получены из командной строки в ключе `--exec`. А основной процесс после этого делает listen  и становится однопоточным сервером, обрабатывающим множество соединений в режиме чтения-записи.

Comment: @Mike *после этого делает listen и становится однопоточным сервером* - совершенно верно. Тот, кто СЛУШАЕТ сокет - однопоточный сервер (в данной программе - putty). Потому, что этот ОДНОПОТОЧНЫЙ сервер реализует ОДНО  соединение по протоколу TELNET (RFC-854) и ему дополнительные процессы/потоки НЕ НУЖНЫ! А кто слушает клавиатуру, по которой стучит пользователь Mike во время сеанса?  Кстати, прямой аналог вопроса TS... А как быть тем серверам, которые поддерживают МНОЖЕСТВО соединений одновременно? Можно реализовать в одном потоке, но будет это жутко неудобно.

Comment: @Sergey Нет, конкретно этот файл uxpgnt.c - это демон авторизации вроде ssh-agent, к пользователям он не имеет отношения и слушает обращения к себе различных программ, работающих с ключами (в том числе одновременные, см. строки select, которые обрабатывают из единой очереди все сокеты, деля их, разумеется на ожидающие чтения и ожидающие записи). А что касается клавиатуры - в unix это обычный файл устройства, который наравне с любыми другими файлами и сокетами отлично обрабатывается одним select.

Comment: @Sergey На счет неудобства. не согласен. никогда такого не замечал. по моему даже очень удобно, когда одна единственная функция select (хотя конечно epoll гораздо круче) сообщает вообще о любых возможных событиях. Вопрос только в том, есть ли какие либо блокирующие поток вызовы, которые невозможно привести к файловым дескрипторам. Но их в unix крайне мало. Мне в одном таком сервере пришлось выносить в отдельный поток библиотеку резолва имен, потому что стандартный libc вызов gethostbyname блокирует поток, а найденная  библиотека предпочитала свой цикл ожидания событий.